# How to query raven db for nservicebus subscriptions

Tags: nservicebus, ravendb

We are upgrading all our NSB 2.6 endpoints to use 3.0. I am upgrading our publisher and am assuming that subscriptions are now stored in raven DB? If so what is the easiest way to see this information?

(complete raven newbie)

When I run http://localhost:8080 I can see the Raven management studio. In the default database there's a document for my endpoint. The contents of this document are

```
{
  "Settings": {
    "Raven/DataDir": "~\\Tenants\\MyEndpointName"
  }
}
```

Is this where I would be able to see subscriptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored in a separate database named after your endpoint. Click the Databases dropdown and select the appropriate db. In this case "MyEndpointName"

Comment: Thanks Andreas - would you be kind enough to have a look at my question here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826024 - it's a follow up to this one. Cheers!