# NServiceBus 3.0 endpoint does not create raven db store

Tags: nservicebus, ravendb

In NSB 2.6 when you define your publisher you can specify the `<DBSubscriptionStorageConfig/>` configuration section to allow you publisher to store subscriptions in a database.

In NSB 3.0 I don't see a way to specify that raven db store the subscriptions. I have kind of assumed that when the publisher first starts it will create a raven db store for itself. I have seen this with other 3.0 endpoints. However, with the specific publisher endpoint I am deploying it doesn't create the raven db store.

Could anyone point me to things I should check are configured correctly?

My endpoint config:

```
internal class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events", StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
    }
}
```

My app config:

```
<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error"/>

<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit" />
```

Much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raven storage is used by default unless you run in the Lite profile. You also seems to miss a call to setup the builder (.DefaultBuilder() ) in your config